# Can I user docker create volume in multicontainer instances of webapp and why

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-files

I have a multi containers webapp deployed with mariadb container, I trying to mount with azure file share but it not work due to directory permission, Can I user docker create volume instead? I test stop start webapp, volume still there, will there be any problem? I couldnt find any explanation, anyone can answer here?
in docker compose file as follow:

```
version: '3.4'
volumes:
    acl-database-data: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure App Service, except mounting the Azure File Share and the persistent storage of app service, the volumes in the docker-compose just create the volumes tempprarily. And you can't create the volumes using the command `docker create volume`. Azure controls the docker command itself and it can't be customized. And when you use the volumes without Azure File Share, then the data will lose if you restart the app service, even if the volume doesn't disappear.

Comment: This is where I confused, I did use docker compose to create volume for database and with stop and Start appservice, data not lost. And after check this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app , it only mention local docker volume not good for scalability, I kind feel something going wrong here

Comment: @ZeHouZhang Which data do you mean? The data you create after the app service is running or the data created when you create the image?